# Json deserialize list vs datatable (several cases)

Tags: json, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datatable, deserialization

I have the following json:

```
{
"Header": {
"MCC": "415",
"FO": "0",
"REGID": "5"
 },
"Contacts": [
{
    "NAME": "jocelyne",
    "MO": "70123456"
},
{
    "NAME": "eliane",
    "MO": "03123456"
}
] }
```

I have 2 clients: one client is giving me this json in this order, the second is giving me the `mo` before `name` in the json, but I need to have the same order in the datatable all the time when I deserialize the json.

What I need to know which is the better way?

1-to deserialize the json in a list (it takes the tags in the alphabetic order) and then convert the list to a datatable

in this case that's what i'm doing:

```
Public Class Dataa
Public MCC As Integer
Public FO As Integer
Public RegId As Integer
Public Contacts As Contacts()
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class Contacts
Public name As String
Public mo As String
End Class

 Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim oFareResults As Generic.List(Of Dataa) = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Dataa))(json)
    contactsDT = ConvertListToDataTable(oFareResults)

    contactsDT.Columns.Add("taken_mo", GetType(String))
    contactsDT.Columns.Add("reg_id", GetType(Integer))

        Private Shared Function ConvertListToDataTable(oFareResults As List(Of Dataa)) As DataTable
    ' New table.
    Dim dtTable As New DataTable()


    dtTable.Columns.Add("name", GetType(String))
    dtTable.Columns.Add("mo", GetType(String))

    For i As Integer = 0 To oFareResults.Item(0).Contacts.Length - 1
        dtTable.Rows.Add(oFareResults(0).Contacts(i).name, oFareResults(0).Contacts(i).mo)
    Next
    Return dtTable
End Function
```

2-to select 2 cases, every case for a different client and then deserialize the json in a datatable

in this case:

```
 Public Class Data
Public Header As Header
Public Contacts As DataTable
End Class

<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract()>
Public Class Header
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="MCC")>
Public MCC As Integer
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="FO")>
Public FO As Integer
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="REGID")>
Public RegId As Integer
End Class

    Dim data As New Data
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Data)(json)
    mcc = data.Header.MCC
    FO = data.Header.FO
    regid = data.Header.RegId
    contactsDT = data.Contacts
```

that's how i have to deserialize the json into a datatable and in this case i have to have 2 functions to deserialize one for every client ( to reserve the order that i need)

Well, what I need to know is not the general solution but I need to know which one has a better performance for the server considering that my json may be very long.
so i need the advantages and disadvantages of each case

Comment: How are you deserializing? Please add a relevant code sample.

Comment: This question should be tagged with [tag:vb.net], not [tag:c#].

Comment: @AlexFilipovici my question is about performance of the server it does not matter if the coding is in vb or c# it's the same method in all cases..